# Is there a more elegant way instead of writing lots of queries?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm building a small blog using GraphQL, Apollo Express and MongoDB with Mongoose.

Currently, articles are fetched by their IDs and visitors can browse an article with the id of let's say "123" here: example.com/articles/123

Instead, I would like to use slugs, so visitors can go to example.com/articles/same-article-as-above

My resolver so far:

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

export default gql`
  extend type Query {
    articles: [Article!]
    article(id: ID!): Article
  }

  type Article {
    id: ID!
    slug: String!
    title: String!
    desription: String!
    text: String!
  }
`;
```

I could just add another query:

```
    articleBySlug(slug: String!): Article
```

This would work perfectly fine. However, this doesn't look very elegant to me and I feel like I am missing some basic understanding. Do I really have to add a new query to my resolvers each time I am trying to fetch an article by its title, text, description or whatever? I would end up with a lot of queries like "articleByTitle", "articleByDate", and so on. Can someone please give me a hint, an example or some best practices (or just confirm that I do have to add more and more queries☺)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to do this is to add all inputs to the same query, and make them optional:

```
export default gql`
  extend type Query {
    articles: [Article!]
    article(id: ID, slug: String, date: String, search: String): Article
  }

  type Article {
    id: ID!
    slug: String!
    title: String!
    description: String!
    text: String!
  }
`;
```

Then, in the resolver just check that exactly one of `id`, `slug` or `date` is provided, and return an error if not.

Another option is to use a search string similar to what Gmail uses (eg `id:x before:2012-12-12`) that you then parse in the resolver.

```
export default gql`
  extend type Query {
    articles: [Article!]
    article(search: String): Article
  }

  type Article {
    id: ID!
    slug: String!
    title: String!
    description: String!
    text: String!
  }
`;
```

A third option is to set up a separate search query that can return several types:

```
export default gql`
  extend type Query {
    articles: [Article!]
    search(query: String!, type: SearchType): SearchResult 
  }

  union SearchResult = Article | User

  enum SearchType {
    ARTICLE
    USER
  }

  type Article {
    id: ID!
    slug: String!
    title: String!
    description: String!
    text: String!
  }

  type User {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    name: String!
  }
`;
```